# Series expansion of $x\sqrt{x^2-1} - \ln(x + \sqrt{x^2-1} )$ at $x=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, power-series, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

In various texts it is stated that a good approximation of,

$x\sqrt{x^2-1} - \ln(x + \sqrt{x^2-1} )$,

about $x=1$ is given by,

$\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{3} (x-1)^{3/2}$.

Plotting the graphs this is indeed the case, however, I am not sure how this approximation is derived. Entering the original equation in Wolfram Alpha it does list the above approximation as the first term in the Puiseux series expansion of the original function. I am not familiar with these and looking online I can't seem to find a way into calculating a Puiseux series for the relevant expression.

Any suggestions or pointers for how to go about this would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @Vilakshan Taylor series won't give fractional power, I did try that but realised it wouldn't work (unless I'm missing something?)

Comment: You differentiate and then resolve at the point about which you are expanding, therefore you plug in a value to get a number and so it doesn't stay as a $\sqrt{x^2-1}$ term

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The Approximation in the Question**

I recognized this as the result of an integral that uses the trigonometric substitution $x=\sec(\theta)$, so I took the derivative of ${\textstyle x\sqrt{x^2-1}-\log\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)}$ and got $2{\textstyle\sqrt{t^2-1}}$. Thus,
$$
{\textstyle x\sqrt{x^2-1}-\log\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)}
=2\int_1^x{\textstyle\sqrt{t^2-1}}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag1
$$
For $t\approx1$, $t^2=(1+(t-1))^2\approx1+2(t-1)=2t-1$; therefore, $\sqrt{t^2-1}\approx\sqrt{2t-2}$. Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\textstyle x\sqrt{x^2-1}-\log\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)
&\approx2\int_1^x\sqrt{2t-2}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag2\\[6pt]
&=\textstyle\frac{4\sqrt2}3(x-1)^{3/2}\tag3
\end{align}
$$

---

**A Better Approximation**

We can get a better approximation if we note that
$$
\begin{align}
\textstyle2\sqrt{t^2-1}
&=\textstyle2\sqrt{2(t-1)+(t-1)^2}\tag{4a}\\
&=\textstyle2\sqrt2\sqrt{t-1}\sqrt{1+\frac{t-1}2}\tag{4b}\\
&\approx\textstyle2\sqrt2\sqrt{t-1}\left(1+\frac{t-1}4\right)\tag{4c}\\
&=\textstyle2\sqrt2\sqrt{t-1}+\frac{\sqrt2}2\sqrt{t-1}^3\tag{4d}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\textstyle x\sqrt{x^2-1}-\log\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)
&\approx2\sqrt2\int_1^x\sqrt{t-1}\,\mathrm{d}t+\frac{\sqrt2}2\int_1^x\sqrt{t-1}^3\,\mathrm{d}t\tag5\\[6pt]
&=\textstyle\frac{4\sqrt2}3(x-1)^{3/2}+\frac{\sqrt2}5(x-1)^{5/2}\tag6
\end{align}
$$

---

**Graphs**

[image]

Comment: i actually was able to  compare the expression with the first line but failed to do the approximation which you did wondrefully using bernoulli..(+1)

Comment: Amazing stuff, can I just ask about the first identity between the expression and the integral, where does that come from? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've just realised that it holds because it's the derivative of the left hand expression that is being integrated. Can you add that info to the start of the answer and then I'll accept? Also... is there a name for this type of approach to finding approximations? Thanks!